# day flag in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a web form through which enables the what events can be booked. One of the parameter is that the event can be booked during any days of the week: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday

The web form contains check boxes for choosing the days. Based on the selection I would like to store the information in a sql table. I am planning to create a secondary master table for the event that will store the information for each day of the week in separate column. With this approach I may ending up wasting spaces.

Below is the table structure of the Primary Master table:

```
PoojaID      int
DeityID      int
WorshipID    int
PoojaName    char
TimeOfPooja  char
Rate         money
```

Please advice on the best approach on how I can store? One way, I thought was to store the info in a single column like Su,Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa

Comment: Why don't you just store the date and use functions to translate the date to the day of week if needed?

Comment: There is a WEEKDAY function that you can use to get int value for the date. You can store the date in your table then.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that the I am creating a master table that will contain the list of events that can be booked and for which days. Booking the events for a specific date will be later

Comment: "that will store the information for each day of the week in separate column" - it would be better to store this data as separate *rows*, one for each day that is of interest. There's nothing, fundamentally, special about a `Tu` value versus a `Th` one, so they ought to be in the same column.

Comment: I would either use separate columns, or create an associative table then.  An event can be allowed on one, many or all days.  As such a single column in the existing table wouldn't work.  As the data is of the same type and purpose, an associative table makes the most sense; as it normalizes the data; but from a performance standpoint, and knowing that we're not going to get more days of the week anytime soon, I'd likely have separate columns in the same table; provided I don't need to report on these values.  If reporting becomes necessary, associative table it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the values in a single column using a binary representation and store it as a tinyint.  Then just store the decimal value.

```
Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Blank | Binary   | Decimal
0      | 0      | 0       | 0         | 0        | 0      | 1        | 0     | 01000000 | 64

Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Blank | Binary   | Decimal
1      | 1      | 1       | 1         | 1        | 1      | 1        | 0     | 01111111 | 127
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Just add one column i.e. event date, and just add another column event day, this column is expression column contains an expression

```
DATENAME(dw, EventDate)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that the I am creating a master table that will contain the list of events that can be booked and for which days. Booking the events for a specific date will be later.